# Formal logic proof validity

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

I am trying to prove the sequent $$\lnot T \to \lnot F,\lnot A \to \lnot T,  F \vdash A. $$
 I thought I had come up with a solution entailing assuming not-A, then using arrow elimination and RAA to prove A. However, I cannot seem to prove the arguments validity using a logic Daemon. Where am I going wrong? I assume somewhere in (7) or (8).

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: It is valid; from the first two premises we get $\lnot A \to \lnot F$ and using Contraposition : $F \to A$. Using Modus Ponens with 3rd premise we get $A$.

Comment: With Natural Deduction, assume $\lnot A$ and derive a contradiction; then conclude by Double Negation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first column indicates the *active assumptions* or *context* under which the statement is derived, and this is typically numbered by the line on which an assumption was raised (by the rule of assumption: $\mathsf A$).   Further, the first three assumptions are premises; the conclusion should have all three active, and no other.

The active assumptions for an inference the active assumptions are the union of the context for the lines from which it is derived, *unless* the rule *discharges* one of the assumptions.   **RAA** is such a rule of discharge.

Reduction Ad Absurdum requires a contradiction to be derived so that one of that line's active assumptions may be discharged. Eg lines 3 and 6 contradict, enabling assumption 4 to be discharged.

$$\boxed{\begin{array}{crlr}
1 & (1) & \neg T\to\neg F & \mathsf A\\
2 & (2) & \neg A\to\neg T & \mathsf A\\
3 & (3) & F &\mathsf A\\
4 & (4) & \neg A&\mathsf A\\
2,4 & (5)& \neg T &2,4~{\to}\mathsf E\\
1,2,4 & (6) & \neg F&1,5~{\to}\mathsf E\\
1,2,3 & (7) & A & 3,6~\mathsf{RAA}~(4)\hspace{-4ex}
\end{array}}$$

Comment: The logic daemon the OP used is [here](https://logic.tamu.edu/daemon.html). It won't recognise your final line as correct as it's written, but you don't need your line $(7)$ anyway. You can use reductio ad absurdum by citing the lines that are contradictory and the line of the assumption you're rejecting as false, as in the following
$$\begin{array}{crlr}
1,2,3 & (7) & A & 3,6~\mathsf{RAA}(4)\ .
\end{array}$$
If you replace your line  $(7)$ with this one (and eliminate your line $(8)\,$), the daemon accepts it as a proof.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you. @lonzaleggiera